# How to wait for all group actions?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I can't wait for group of `SKAction` because completion handler executes immediately. Here is basic example:

```
let a1 = SKAction.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.5, duration: duration), onChildWithName: child1.name!)
let a2 = SKAction.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1, duration: duration), onChildWithName: child2.name!)

runAction(SKAction.group([a1, a2]), completion: { () -> Void in
    // do something
})
```

Nodes `child1` and `child2` are children of scene. When I run app on iPhone 5s (iOS 8.4) simulator I see that completion block doesn't wait while group actions finished and starts immediately.

So my two questions:

1. Is it s bug? If no, where is in `SKAction` documentation I can find explanation of this behaviour.
2. How to do this right? I know I can use counter and start each action `a1` and `a2` with completion block and just check when counter became 0 but it looks like a boilerplate code for me.

Comment: Do you have a warning said `SKScene: Animating the position of a SKScene has no effect.`?

Comment: @WangYudong no, all animations work fine without any warnings and exactly like I need.

Comment: It's weird that an hour ago I can reproduce your issue, but now everything's OK. See my sample project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqsnyh0czha0ymh/GroupAction.zip?dl=0).

Comment: I removed move animation and also checked your project and it is still print `complete` before fade out animation ends. I tested on iPhone 5s (iOS 8.4) simulator.

Comment: I noticed the phenomenon that grouping `a1` and `a2` only will make the completion block run at once. But I think the problem might be caused by `SKAction.runAction(SKAction, onChildWithName:)`. Simply using `SKAction.fadeAlphaTo()` for example, and grouping two of them will act like what you expect. Maybe you need an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation, `SKAction.runAction` returns an action of instantaneous duration (that is 0 duration).

Thus in your code both `SKActions`, `a1` and `a2`, have instantaneous duration. This is why the completion block is called immediately.

From Apple Documentation

> `SKAction.runAction` : This action has an instantaneous duration,
>   although the action executed on the child may have a duration of its
>   own.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runAction:onChildWithName:

One way to set the completion handler would be to set it to one of the child nodes, since both actions have the same duration.

```
let a1 = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.5, duration: 1);
let a2 = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1, duration: 1);

child1.runAction(a1)
child2.runAction(a2) { () -> Void in
    //completion code
}
```